# javascript function not called on buttonclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Login page</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:red;">
        I was just thinking that I could do us a private lil webpage ^^
    I love you so much hun! <3

        <form name="Wish">
            Wish<input type="text" name="wish"/>
            <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="sendtoajax(this.form)" />
            <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
        </form>

<script language="javascript">

function sendtoajax(form){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
alert('done')
 }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("form.wish.value");
}

</script>


    </body>
</html>
```

I want to execute the function on button click and if I just leave it plain so it executes immidiatelly it work but when I put it into a function and I call it on button click it doesnt at all...

Comment: my guess is, that the native html-form gets submitted _before_ the js-function gets fired. Try changing `input submit` to a simple `button`, that doesn't send the form.

Answer (score 1):

Change `type="button"` of `input`. If `input` has type="submit" it `submits` the `form` and hence your function will not be called.

```
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="sendtoajax(this.form)" />
```

Comment: Well Ill be damned :D It worked right away! Thanks guys, working with php, javascript and such first day so this thing was invisible to me... THANKS SO MUCH for such an early response!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Login page</title>
        <script language="javascript">
            function sendtoajax(){
                var xmlhttp=window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                        alert('done')
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.php",true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.send( 'wish='+document.querySelectorAll('input[name="wish"]')[0].value );
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:red;">
        I was just thinking that I could do us a private lil webpage ^^ I love you so much hun! <3

        <form name='Wish'>
            <label>Wish<input type="text" name="wish" /></label>
            <input type="button" class="button" value='Wish now' onclick="sendtoajax()" />
            <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `<form>` submits and redirects. AJAX forms are not meant to redirect. Either give `return false;` like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" onclick="sendtoajax(this.form); return false;" />
```

---

Or give an `event.preventDefault()` in your AJAX code:

```
function sendtoajax(form) {
  //----
  //----
  //----
  return false;
}
```

If you can do with jQuery, it is very easy. Lemme take the same code of yours, and convert it to jQuery in a simple way and explain you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <title>Login page</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: red;">
    I was just thinking that I could do us a private lil webpage ^^
    I love you so much hun! &lt;3

    <form name="Wish" id="Wish">
      Wish <input type="text" name="wish" />
      <input type="submit" class="button" />
      <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
    </form>

    <script language="javascript">
      $(function () {
        $("#Wish").submit(function () {
          $.post("ajax.php", $(this).serialize(), function () {
            alert("Submitted");
          });
        });
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```